# Errors in ROS:helloworld on Arduino

Tags: ros, arduino

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm really new to ROS and Arduino. I get a problem in arduino . When I finished installing the Arduino IDE in Ubunto 12.04 , I test the helloworld program in ros_lib, it remind me like this:fatal error: ros/node_handle.h no such file or directory.
SO , is there anyone could help me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/150176/errors-in-ros:helloworld-on-arduino/) by [berry0511](https://answers.ros.org/users/14546/berry0511/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is the ros_lib in the sketchbook/libraries folder?

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2014-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [berry0511](https://answers.ros.org/users/14546/berry0511/) on 2014-04-08**:
Yes, I copied from the rosserial_arduino/libraries,but there accurs anther error, returns like "permission denied",however the ros_lib shows up in the sketchbook/libraries. amazing?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2014-04-08**:
Slightly, is your sketchbook in your home folder?

**Comment by [berry0511](https://answers.ros.org/users/14546/berry0511/) on 2014-04-08**:
yes, Automatically generated in home folder